# connect to remote mysql db server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, remote-server

I need to get a dump of database from a remote mysql server. I have the remote server ip, username and password but when I try to connect from mysql workbench it fails  with error message 'cannot connect to mysql server"ip address" (10060)'
I tried to ping the ip of server from cmd but it timed out. What am I missing ?Is there a way of connecting to this server? 
Unfortunately, all I have are these details n am not sure if my IP has access or was added or not. Also noway for me to check. Last person who connected remotely has left 1 yr. back and there is no IT staff to resolve this. I just wanted to know if there is anyway of getting the db dump from server

Comment: Get in touch with your IT staff. You obviously are not able to connect the server at all

Comment: See [MySQL Workbench: Connection Creation and Trouble Shooting (for beginners)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY&list=PLWx5a9Tn2EvH0q2WXpUBqptxi5640qk9O) for problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is the server machine because you cannot ping it.

You can only connect to a MySQL database server if there are an actual running machine. Having not able to ping the ip address is the first obvious problem.

Should you have able to confirm that there are really a database server that is running for that ip address, only then you can try your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to get access of database from a remote mysql server.

1. Login to Cpanel
2. Goto "Remote MySQL"
3. Add Access Host [% => for access from all IP. or Add your Own IP]
4. Click Add Host.

Then you can access Database from remote.

Comment: Thanks all, unfortunately, all I have are these details n m not sure if my IP was added or not n noway for me to check. Last person who connected remotely has left 1 yr. back and  there is no IT staff to resolve this. I just wanted to know if there is anyway of getting the db dump from server ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user on the mysql like username@IP_address_of_workbench to access it